# Delphi FMX External Testing is not supported for builds that have been created with a beta version of XCode, OS X or IOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Building an App in Delphi Xe8
We can Submit the app to the store - and get no errors with the submit
After submitting an app to the apple store getting this message in the prerelease section

> External Testing is not supported for builds that have been created
>   with a beta version of XCode, OS X or IOS
>
> [image]

The last time we were able to submit for external testing was 7 Aug 2015

Were running 
XCode 6.4 (6E35b)
OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)

Tried to build using two different devices 
IOS 8.4 (12H143)
IOS 8.4.1 (12H321)

We have also tried submitting a sample app in delphi XE8 and are running into the same issue.

This is the Delphi Generated app - the submit for external testing is disabled

> [image: Delphi Generated App]

We have built another app using XCode - not Delphi - on the same machine and it can be submitted for external testing.

> [image]

We also created an app using Xamarin and the External testing option is available

> [image: Xamarin Generated App]

These were generated on the same MAC

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Has anyone been able to submit a delphi Xe8 app after 2015-08-25 and have the external testing enabled?

Comment: I successfully submitted on 8/18/2015.

Comment: has anyone been able to submit for external testing with a Delphi app from 25-07-2015?

Comment: I submitted today (8-28-2015) too to Testflight.

Comment: Did you have to add any plist settings to get the external testing enabled?

Comment: The only custom key we added was: <key>DTPlatformName</key><string>iphoneos</string>

Comment: Weird - next time we push up an update ill try removing some of the other settings we added and see if we can narrow down why it wasn't enabling external testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, this appears to be related to issue [RSP-11653](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11653), which suggests DTSDKBuild is the problem.  For SDK 9.2, I was able to use:

```
<key>DTSDKBuild</key>
<string>13C75</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

We got it to enable "submit for Beta App Review"

> [image: Working External testing]

came down to PList Settings

we have added the following to the Project > Options > Version info | for the IOS Device

right click in the Key Section and add the following
**These are the settings that worked for us - may be different on other MAC's**

DTPlatformname = iphoneos
DTSDKName = iphoneos8.4
DTXcode = 0640 
DTSDKBuild = 12H141
BuildMachineOSBuild = 14F27
DTCompiler = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0

> [image: PList info]

Something must have changed within the last few weeks
Im not sure which of these settings were needed to make it work or if all of them were needed.

Answer (score 1):

DTSDKBuild 12H141 equates to Xcode version 6.4 (build 6E35b). Updating it to 13E230 (bringing it up to Xcode version 7.3) resolved a similar issue for me when trying to do Test Flight External Testing.

I can't tell you why, but I suspect that since 12* allowed for compilation to iOS 7.x devices (and we can't submit new apps for release under iOS 7.x) that perhaps the error is more of an invalid version of XCode error than a beta version of XCode error.

As far as I know 6.4 was not a beta version.